# Parse name from full email address in PHP

Tags: php, html-entities, html-encode

I would like to get name from full email address and tried htmlentities and html_entity_decode but special character `<` and `>` gives issue to get the name. As full email address is coming from array (key-value) not as a string.

## Array value:

```
Array
(
   [ENV_MAIL] => "Project Bribara<project.bribara@gmail.com";
)
```

## Tried code:

```
// Project email
$environment['ENV_MAIL'] = "Project Bribara<project.bribara@gmail.com";
$projectEmail = $environment['ENV_MAIL'];
echo $projectEmail ;
$projectName = explode("@", htmlentities($adminEmail));
echo html_entity_decode($projectName);
```

## Expected:

```
"Project Bribara"
```

## Actual:

```
"Project Bribara<project.bribara
```

How can I get the output as per expected?

Comment: If you have this string `Project Bribara<project.bribara@gmail.com` Why can't you explode on `<`

Comment: Special character < gives issue, already tried that.

Comment: Are you expecting something like this https://eval.in/853973 ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is value is coming from array (not string) so this explode didn't work. For that reason, i tried htmlentities and html_entity_decode but no luck. Your code is great for string.

Comment: Can you share `print_r` of your array and expected output ?

Comment: You can try this one. https://eval.in/853977

Comment: Got the answer to use html_entity_decode.

Comment: AFAICS, the email address is malformed; the closing `>` is missing.  I suppose it is sufficiently comprehensible to be usable, but it's on thin  ice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can tackle this issue:  ([Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf667c16a82d3a5b8a6b8f3c3fc468a83e34b54c))

The reason that all of the other answers fail is because you have misrepresented your input string.  Your actual input string contains `&lt;` which is the html entity for `<`.  My methods below will clarify this point to future SO readers and help you to select the best approach for your project.

```
$environment['ENV_MAIL']="Project Bribara&lt;project.bribara@gmail.com";
//                                       ^^^^ html entity causing you trouble

$decoded_string=html_entity_decode($environment['ENV_MAIL']);  // convert "&lt;" to "<"
var_export(explode('<',$decoded_string));  // generate an array of the two parts for future access

echo "\n\n";

echo "Project Name = ",strstr($decoded_string,'<',true);  // use strstr on < of decoded string with "true" param

echo "\n\n";

echo "Project Email = ",substr($decoded_string,strpos($decoded_string,'<')+1);  // use substr&strpos on <

echo "\n\n";

// or less potentially damaging to your input string...
var_export(explode('&lt;',$environment['ENV_MAIL']));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Project Bribara',
  1 => 'project.bribara@gmail.com',
)

Project Name = Project Bribara

Project Email = project.bribara@gmail.com

array (
  0 => 'Project Bribara',
  1 => 'project.bribara@gmail.com',
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this. Here we are using `explode()` function to split a string.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/853977)

```
$environment['ENV_MAIL'] ="Project Bribara<project.bribara@gmail.com";
echo explode("<",$environment['ENV_MAIL'])[0];
```

Comment: Your solution is good and upvoted but due htmlentities in the value (which may not be visible) gives issue to explode or substr doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Substr and strpos.
Substr splits the string from first character to where strpos finds the `<`.

```
$str = "Project Bribara<project.bribara@gmail.com";
// Or ^^ is $projectEmail if I understand it correct?

Echo substr($str, 0, strpos($str , "<"));
```

https://3v4l.org/qSF4h

If the `<` causes problems maybe you can try regex?

https://regex101.com/r/EfkwLX/1

```
// Match a-Z and space multiple until non word character
$re = '/([a-zA-Z ]+)\W/';
$str = 'Project Bribara<project.bribara@gmail.com';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

Echo $matches[1];
```

https://3v4l.org/fuEL5

Comment: @Alive don't know if it is as OP says that there is a problem with `<` then my answer will fail too. Or?

Comment: In that case every-ones fails :):). I think OP using `htmentities()` multiple times and that is causing the issue

Comment: Your solution is good and upvoted but due htmlentities in the value (which may not be visible) gives issue to explode or substr doesn't work at all. Can you suggest something using regex?

Comment: Got the answer to use html_entity_decode.

Comment: @Jitesh updated with regex. But keep in mind regex is slower than normal explode or string operations.

Answer (score 1):

You should **split** the string into the **name** and **email addres**s using "**<**" first. And then **split** with the "**@**" if you wish.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Project email
$environment['ENV_MAIL'] = "Project Bribara<project.bribara@gmail.com";
$projectEmail = $environment['ENV_MAIL'];
echo $projectEmail;
$projectName = html_entity_decode ($projectEmail);
echo $projectName;
```